# I'm getting compiler debug error while deploying my erc20 token on etherium testnet

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, bep20

### Every time I'm trying to deploy my token contract on the test net, I'm facing this error:

> Compiler debug log:  Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and
> ABI  Found the following ContractName(s) in source code: SafeMath,
> Token  But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
> For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the
> Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

[This is the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quxHl.png)

This is my code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed 
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
library SafeMath {
    function Add(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function Sub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function Mul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function Div(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}

contract Token{
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    string public name = 'MY TOKEN';
    string public symbol = 'MTK';
    uint256 public decimals = 18 ;
    uint256 public totalsupply = 10000000000000000000000 ;
    address owner;
    //5% will go to owner and 5% of transaction will burn
    uint taxfee = 5;
    uint burnfee = 5;
    bool public istransferable = false;

    //bool public ExcludedFromReward = false;


    //exclude addresses from deflation
    mapping(address=>bool) public ExcludedFromFee;
    //mapping(address=>bool) public ExcludedFromReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balance;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowance;
    mapping (address => bool) public _Blacklisted;  

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    event OwnershipTransfer(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor(){//(string memory Name, string memory Symbol, uint Decimals, uint TotalSupply) {
        // name = Name;
        // symbol = Symbol;
        // decimals = Decimals;
       // totalsupply = TotalSupply; 
        owner = msg.sender;
        balance[owner] = totalsupply;//TotalSupply;
        ExcludedFromFee[owner] = true;
         _rOwned[msg.sender] = _rTotal;
    }
    function Balance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return balance[owner];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `safetmath` library contains public functions. As mentioned in the Solidity documentation, if your library contains public functions, then the EVM will use a DELEGATECALL to invoke the function.
However, if your library contains internal functions, then those functions will be inlined in the bytecode of the contract.
So, you have two options:

1. Change the visibility of your library functions to `internal`
2. Deploy the library on the testnet and [link it](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/using-the-compiler.html?highlight=library#library-linking) to the bytecode of the contract